# What does "bound" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> The bronze, 8-foot-tall LBJ sculpture is slated to be installed at downtown's Little Tranquility Park, **bound by** Capitol, Walker, Bagby and Smith streets. ([source](https://www.chron.com/news/houston-texas/houston/article/Lyndon-Baines-Johnson-statue-could-be-coming-to-12960920.php))

Judging from the context, I think "bound by" here means "connected with" or "restricted by," but I can't find a similar meaning in the verb "bind" or the adjective "bound." What does it mean here exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/search/+Little+Tranquility+Park/@29.7611549,-95.3688381,18.25z) makes the meaning clear: those four streets comprise the boundary of Little Tranquility Park. But there is a definite mistake (to me, at least) in that sentence: it should be "bounded" (the past participle of "bound"), rather than "bound" (the past participle of "bind").

Incidentally, the spelling "tranquillity" (with two l's) is still preferred over "tranquility" (with one l), but [it's a close thing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tranquility%2Ctranquillity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctranquility%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctranquillity%3B%2Cc0). I wouldn't have mentioned it, but Google Maps has both spellings! You will find both Tranquillity Park and Little Tranquility Park on the linked page.

Comment: I agree about the mistake. "Bound" means "tied". "Bounded" means "surrounded by boundaries".